# Watch for new div appended

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i watch if div is added/appended, i have the following:

```
<div class="columns">...</div>
<div class="columns">...</div>
<div class="columns">...</div>
```

I have an button **add more** witch will append the new div's, my problem is how to watch is another div is added.

My goal is to push the input data from the new div pappend to the existing array.

In the divs i have inputs like:

```
<div class="columns"><input type="text" name="device_id[]" ></div>
```

I save the input values linke:

```
device_id = $('input:enabled[name="device_id[]"]').map(function () {
    return $(this).val(); // $(this).val()
}).get();
```

So i need to push the new input data from the new div to the existing array **device_id**

Comment: _"my problem is how to watch is another div is added"_ - When the button has been clicked, or did I miss something?

Comment: When the div is added, i need to pass the new div data to an existing array.

Comment: Why is this requirement not part of the question? And why would you need to add it to an array? Maybe you're better of with a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) returned by [`.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) which will automatically update its content.

Answer (score 1):

> I have an button add more witch will append the new div's...

In your **add more** button function insert code **AFTER** you append the `div`

For example:

```
let arr = [];

function addMore(){
    // div to append...
    var el = <div class="columns"></div>

    // target to append the div
    id.append(ed);

    //ADD CODE HERE AS THE DIV HAS BEEN APPENDED.......
    // Example
    arr.push(el);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks this is more helpful, i just need to push the inputs data to the array not the entire html any help with that ?

Comment: @Edo _"i just need to push the inputs data to the array"_ - Yet another information that is missing from your question...

Comment: Where are you appending the divs data? if its in the same function call just pass it in the arr.push(DATA);

Comment: Yes i know, my goal is to push the inputs data from the div added to the existing array.

Comment: @Andreas - its a visual example, not tried and tested code... besides, the answer provides help to the original question.

Comment: @Edo, update your question with the full code (inputs, data, functions etc.. ) and id be more than happy to help. Let me know when you've updated. Cheers.

Comment: @LukeWalker  i have updated my question and addend the first part where i save the data.

Comment: @LukeWalker any help ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found it. I had a small mistake with the name of the appended inputs.

I changed the names then I got the right result! Already everything was working.

```
device_id = $('input:enabled[name="device_id[]"]').map(function () {}
```

The answer is here `input:enabled[name="device_id[]` this will map all inputs that are **:enabled** anytime any input.

Answer (score 0):

> I have an button **add more** witch will append the new div's...

Use an event handler on that button, since you know it adds divs.

If you need to know if something **else** adds divs to some container, you can use a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) using the `subtree` option.

Comment: any examples for me ?